# Is it possible to make a small image format ad?

Tags: android, admob

I found two kind of ads in the admob tutorials. Banner and interstitial however I would like to do some small ads which are like image size to use inside a article is this possible or are the only ads they support banner and interstitial?

Answer (score 0):

The only ad formats that are supported are banner and interstitial.